# IIS 10 with a new SSL Certificate installed will continue accepting http requests or only https?

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, iis-10

On IIS 10 Windws Server 2016, my clients access the website using the following domain
"http://example.net" and that is the "Site Binding" that is setup for this domain. I purchased a SSL certificate and want to instal it adding this "https://example.net" to the
"Site Binding" on IIS 10 and leave BOTH bindings for a couple of days until I can go to the client's site and change the browser's shortcuts from "http://example.net" to "https//..." then after that I will delete the "http://..." binding in the IIS. My question is: Will this arrangement work or will the clients be blocked once the certificate is installed ? I know the short answer would be to tell them to just add the "s" after http in all their computers but it is not that simple.

Comment: "Will this arrangement work", you can help yourself by experiments. "it is not that simple", it is also not hard to add HTTP to HTTPS redirection (as most of everyone does that).

Comment: Lex Li I don't feel confortable experimenting on a live site with the risk to disrupt their bussiness. Regarding the redirection, most of them access using a shortcut and some of the users don't even know what address bar means.

Comment: You don't need to experiment on production environment, as such can be easily emulated on a single machine (even a Windows 10 laptop) by mocking up DNS and using self signed certificates. You can find tons of articles over the internet showing how simple HTTP to HTTPS redirection can be done via IIS URL Rewrite module, and your users don't notice the changes (and that's why today almost every sites do that).

Comment: I appreciatte your help but I would prefer a direct answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete the http binding on IIS, it will only accept https requests.

Install new certificate on IIS, there are a few things to note.

1. Client should also update the client certificate so that it can verify the server client.
2. Server need to restart after installing so that the new certificate can work. Otherwise old certificate will still show in browser, even old certificate has been deleted on server.